# Flower with red blooms and six petals

Tags: identification

What is this plant with red blooms and apparently six petals (diameter of blooms: approx. 2-3 cm; location: Central Europe)? I find it quite attractive in its hanging pot.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Pelargonium (common name: Geranium). Based on the leaves and habit, a hanging variety (sometimes also called an Ivy Geranium). I don't recognize the variety; typically the flower clusters are tighter than the ones shown.

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed a Pelargonium, but judging by the flower form, I think it's what's commonly known as a Cascade Geranium, proper name Pelargonium peltatum, although its flower stems seem a little long for that variety. Useful as summer bedding in hanging pots and window boxes because of their 'cascading' habit, they are generally smaller and tidier in growth habit than ivy leafed (also known as trailing) pelargoniums, though they have a similar leaf structure; the flower form is more open and lax when compared to the flowers on other pelargoniums. Images here https://plantsgallery.blogspot.com/2012/06/pelargonium-peltatum-cascade-leucht.html